# NLP in R: working with tokenization in a CONLLU-style dataframe

Tags: r, nlp, tokenize, udpipe, conll

I am working in a Portuguese Digital Humanities project using R. I created a CONLLU-style dataframe with the corpus data, using the UDPipe library:

```
textAnnotated <- udpipe::udpipe_annotate(m_port, x = textCorpus) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

The beginning of my dataframe is like this:

```
doc_id   paragraph_id sentence_id   sentence            token_id  token            
1   doc1            1           1   DICCIONARIO DOS...         1  DICCIONARIO
2   doc1            1           1   DICCIONARIO DOS...       2-3  DOS
3   doc1            1           1   DICCIONARIO DOS...         2  DE
4   doc1            1           1   DICCIONARIO DOS...         3  OS
5   doc1            1           1   DICCIONARIO DOS...         4  TERMOS
6   doc1            1           1   DICCIONARIO DOS...         5  TECHCNICOS
```

What I would like to do is to mark each token in each corresponding sentence; for instance, I could rewrite each sentence with the corresponding token as bold.
For example, the first sentence is "DICCIONARIO DOS TERMOS TECHNICOS". I need to replace the sentence in number one with `<b>DICCIONARIO</b> DOS TERMOS TECHNICOS`; and then, the sentence in number two would be `DICCIONARIO <b>DOS</b> TERMOS TECHNICOS`; the sentence in number five (because numbers 3 and 4 would be deleted) would be `DICCIONARIO DOS <b>TERMOS</b> TECHNICOS`; and so on.

I cannot simply match the token in the sentence with, say, `str_replace()`, because the same token may occur multiple times in one sentence.

At first, I thought that I could use the function `word(token, token_id)` to find the token in the sentence and replace it by, say, `<b>token</b>`, with a code like that:

```
for(i in 1:length(textAnnotated$doc_id)) {

textAnnotated$sentence[i] <- sub(word(TextAnnotated$sentence[i], TextAnnotated$token_id[i]),
                                 paste0("<b>",
                                       word(TextAnnotated$sentence[i], 
                                       TextAnnotated$token_id[i]),
                                        "</b>"),
                             textAnnotated$sentence[i])
}
```

But there are two problems with that:

1. Some token numbers are marked "2-3", because of contractions ("dos" = "de + os"). I wrote a simple code that solves this problem by deleting all the uncontracted forms and renumbering the tokens:

```
for(i in 1:length(textAnnotated$token_id)){
  if(str_detect(textAnnotated$token_id[i], "-")){
    textAnnotated$token_id[i+1] <- 0
    textAnnotated$token_id[i+2] <- 0
  }
}
textAnnotated <- subset(textAnnotated, token_id!=0)
for(k in 1:length(textAnnotated$sentence_id)){

  for(j in 1:length(textAnnotated$token_id[textAnnotated$sentence_id == k])){
  
    textAnnotated$token_id[textAnnotated$sentence_id == k][j] <- j
  }
}
```

2. But there is a second problem: punctuation (commas, parentheses etc.) also counts as tokens for the UDPipe annotator, but not for the `word()` function; besides that, the `word()` function identifies a string such as "word)," as a word, instead of just "word" (I suppose it is because it only uses blankspace as a separator).

I was wondering if there is a function similar to `word()` that also counts punctuation characters as tokens, but ignores them in returning the result. Or maybe someone could point me another way to solve this. Thank you!

Comment: Could you create a [reprex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? It will be easier to help you if we have an example sentence and your expected output.

Comment: Sorry, it was confusing. I edited and tried to clarify my intentions in the text. I want to have a list of sentences in which each token is marked as bold in its corresponding sentence, so that token[1] is marked as bold in sentence[1], token[2] is marked as bold in sentence[2] and so on.